# Calculation of nettotal using Object class in android

Tags: android, object, shopping-cart

I have a product object which is I'm using to add `Product` which are adding to the cart.

`Product.java` object (I have `getters` and `setters`),

```
public class Product {

    public double price;
    public String description;
    public int quantity;
    public String instructions;
    public double subTotal;

    public Product(String description, int quantity, String instructions,
            double subTotal, double price) {

        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.instructions = instructions;
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }
}
```

This object is belong to each item is been added to the cart. I want to find the net total of each item is being added to the cart. It is like if I have added 3 items to the cart then total of 3 `subTotal`.

In my activity I tried to access the `subtotal` by using,

```
total = Product.subTotal;
```

then I changed the `subtotal` to `static` then all the item prices change to last item added to the cart.

My problem is how can I get the total of each item added to the cart from my activity. So I can find the nettotal. Any advises will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some more understanding of object oriented programming. `static` means, that the field (`subtotal` in your case) does not belong to the `Product` instance. But since `subTotal` is a attribute for each instance of `Product` it may not be `static` so that its related to `Product`. [Read more on static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

To calculate the `total`, you have to iterate about your `Product` instance and sum all `subTotals`, e.g. like this:

```
// empty List
List<Product> myProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
myProducts.add(new Product("description",1, "instructions", 5, 7));
[...]
double total = 0;
for(Product product : myProducts) {
   total += product.subTotal * product.quantity;
}
System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I got the idea and was able to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Make you cart an `ArrayList` of products.

product will have method

```
  public double getsubtotal()
    {
       return price*quantity;
    }
```

and total will itrate through the cart

```
for(Product prod:cart)
{
   total = total + prod.getsubtotal
}
```